# tortoiseGit Reset to a previous version

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, tortoisegit, git-revert

i am using tortoise Git and i just did a merge and push that made my project not starting any more, it has added some `HEAD` elements and stuff.. now i want to rollback to the moment before i made the merge how can i achieve that?

Should I do a reset "in that case soft,mix or hard?"..? or should i revert all commits after my last working commit? switch/checkout to the last working commit? merge to the last working commit .. or simply create a new branch from the last working commit?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand "*push that made my project not starting any more, it has added some HEAD elements and stuff..*", so I just assume you "*push that branch to remote*."

---

If you have some co-workers, the *normal flow* will be:

1. don't change anything you pushed out
2. Revert
3. Commit
4. Push

---

If you don't have any co-worker, do whatever you want to do. :p

My usual way:

1. Reset with Hard
2. Push with force